# why does C3 chart does not work when parameter is provided as String?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have C3 chart which works when the columns are provided directly but does not work when provided as string param.

Here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q8h39/79/

***Javascript code:***

```
 dataval = "[['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250], ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]]";

 var chart = c3.generate({
   bindto: '#chart1',
   data: {
     x: 'x',
     xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
     columns: dataval
   },
   axis: {
     x: {
       type: 'timeseries',
       tick: {
         format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
       }
     }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is this is a string *(enclosed with in double quotes)*

```
"[['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250], ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]]"
```

And this is an array object:

```
[['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250], ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]]
```

In c3 `columns` expects an array object not a string

**EDIT**

To convert the string you passed into JSON array do like this:

```
dataval = "[['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250], ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]]";
dataval = dataval.replace(/'/g, "\"");//replacing single quotes with double quotes
dataval = JSON.parse(dataval);
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/5k4c19jw/1)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I found that but what if I am giving this parameter from java and I am storing it in variable.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer but I am still having problem with my data `Uncaught Error: x is not defined for id` . I can see array in my console too.

Comment: corrected the code you wrote this `dataval = dataval.replace(/'/g, "\'");` but it should be `dataval = dataval.replace(/'/g, '\"');` fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/5k4c19jw/3/